# Options Menu in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I have the following code :

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as ttk 
from ttk import *

win=Tk()
OPTIONS=["PIM","RR"]
var = StringVar()
option = OptionMenu(win, var, *OPTIONS )
option.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

The code creates a window witha single drop down list with RR and PIM with PIM set by default.
The problem is that when RR is selected PIM disappears from the list.

Comment: On my copy of 2.7, the code above gives me an option list with nothing selected by default, and the two choices, of which neither disappears when one is selected. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter is `default` value that is selected. And the fourth parameter is values. So it should be specified as follow:

```
option = OptionMenu(win, var, OPTIONS[0], *OPTIONS)
```

FYI, here's the signature of the `OptionMenu.__init__` method:

```
__init__(self, master, variable, default=None, *values, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This reference does not include the default parameter: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/optionmenu.html -- it may be out of date.

Comment: This reference also doesn't include it: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/optionmenu.htm

Comment: However, in my copy of 2.7, this is the signature: `Tkinter.OptionMenu(self, master, variable, value, *values, **kwargs)` which is the same as you said.